# What is the simplest way to secure internal WCF 4.0 REST Services between WebServer and ApplicationServer?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-rest

I have a number of WCF 4.0 rest services on an internal application server which are accessed from a DMZ'd public facing web server. Essentially I am looking for the simplest way to restrict access to the services to calls from the web server and select internal accounts. It seems like a simple task of which I can find no simple answer.

Info:

- IIS6 for both the web server and the application server
- .NET 4
- Web Server is not a part of a trusted domain
- REST Services are 100% code.
- Client calls are passing credentials via System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials ( not sure if this is the way to go )

Comment: Great idea. Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: can use use certificates ? it can be a good way of securing (at least, one of the techniques you can use to raise the security)

Answer (score 0):

For the network part, you can disallow all IP's except the one of the ones you trust in [IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/7586f163-2098-4719-a40b-065b2217d7ba.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: That's what I would like to do, but the client wants to secure the services via authentication. This also doesn't solve the internal access issue.